# How to select Ubuntu at startup?

Tags: boot, grub2

I've installed Ubuntu 11.04 on my xp inside windows through image file.
But I'm not able to select Ubuntu at startup because theselection screen appears only for a fraction of a second.

Comment: hey frns thnx for your commnts bt i believe these solns are for linux terminals .how do i solve this thro' xp or bios? coz i cant boot into linux.

Answer (score 1):

I belive this is what you are looking for.
`sudo nano /etc/default/grub`
And then change the line 
`GRUB_TIMEOUT` to `GRUB_TIMEOUT=20` to make the menu appear for 20 seconds.
Remeber to `sudo update-grub` after you saved the file. Then reboot, and the menu should display for 20 seconds.

Comment: Hold down SHIFT at boot and the menu should appear.

Answer (score 0):

Install grub-optimizer and change the time-out setting.

[image]

Installation:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install grub-customizer
```